# UITableViewのSelfSizingCellについて

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

StoryBoardは使わずコードのみでTableViewを作成しています。
UITableViewを継承したTableViewのカスタムクラスに、２つのカスタムセルのクラスを登録し、
セルの行によって、UITableViewCellクラスと２つのカスタムクラスの、計三種類のセルを
SelfSizingCellとして表示したいのですが、警告が出てしまいます。
TableViewの設定としては

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

上記のコードを書いています。
警告は以下です。

> Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously
>   suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're
>   considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height
>   instead.

TableViewの高さを返すメソッド（`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`）を実装すればこの警告は消えるのですが、そうするとセルの高さがすべて固定されてしまいます。
カスタムセルクラスが一つの場合は警告が出ないので、複数の（カスタム）セルクラスを使用していることが原因かと思っております。
どのようにしたら警告が出なくなるのでしょうか？
お知恵をお貸し頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: セル内の`Constraint`が正しくセッティングされていれば、期待どおり可変になると思われます。そこを再確認してみてはいかがですか？

Comment: コメント頂きましてありがとうございます！仰る通り、各カスタムセル内のconstraintの設定は行った上で動かすと、セルの高さは計算されて可変にはなっているようです。ただ、警告が出ているので本当に正しく計算されているのか、好ましい状態であるのか、疑問に思いまして質問致しました。

Comment: 警告が出ている以上、「好ましい状態」でないのは、疑う余地はないでしょう。Constraintのセッティング（高さ方向のConstraint）の不備（まあ「破綻」ですね）を探し出すことです。Storyboard、Interface Builderで、プログラムでセッティングしたConstraintsを、再現すれば、視覚的にどこに破綻があるか、すぐにわかるのではないですか？

Comment: 頂いたコメントを参考に各カスタムセルのconstraintの高さの制約を見直したところ警告が出なくなりました！ありがとうございます！